# OData - How to expand navigation property of base entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, odata, odata-v4

I'm using Asp.Net WebApi Odata V4 with Entity Framework 6.
I'm trying to expand navigation property of a derived class, but im getting below error.

Base Entity

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("CreatedUser")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedUser { get; set; }
}
```

Entity

```
public class Book: BaseEntity
{
    public int BookId {get;set;}
}
```

Odata Model Builder

```
builder.EntityType<BaseEntity>();
builder.EntitySet<Book>("Books");
```

Odata Query

```
http://localhost/svc/Books(1)?$expand=CreatedUser
```

Error:

> The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'App.Models.Book' and a
>   check of type 'App.Models.BaseEntity' is not supported. Only entity
>   types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: This question looks a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126471/the-typeis-expression-with-an-input-of-type-domain-entities-request-and-a-ch). Can you find an answer there?

Comment: I think you shouldn't register `BaseEntity`.

Comment: @GertArnold No, Same error occurs even if i didn't register `BaseEntity`

Comment: @GWigWam Tried that suggestions, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For your model builder, do not register `BaseEntity` as an  *EntityType*, instead use the concrete type:

```
builder.EntityType<Book>();
builder.EntitySet<Book>("Books");
```